# Only Show specific word from a string

Tags: ms-access

I'm currently learning Access 2016 since i find it works wonders with Excel.

However i'm trying to find the correct SQL code for detecting certain words in Long Text and only output these words not the text itself

Here is the setup

> Fieldname: **Type**
>
> **Long Text**
>
> Cell Information
>
> Cell1: Johan have a nice car
>
> Cell2: Jane road a bike.
>
> Cell3: Janes bike was red
>
> Output
>
> Cell1: **car**
>
> Cell2: **bike**
>
> Cell3: **bike**

I'm only interested in keeping certain words from these strings when the query is done, and they should be output to the same Fieldname, i have tried to locate this information for the most part of the day and my last hope of sanity was to check in here if someone has an idea of which function i should be using.

Thank you for your time

Comment: The function you're looking for is InStr()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to use VBA for this, depending on how big your list of words is, but one way to do it with SQL, assuming a relatively small and FIXED list of words:

```
IIF(<Mytext> LIKE '*car*','car',IIF(<Mytext> LIKE '*bike*','bike',''))
```

Comment: This worked well for the few words i was looking for. Thank you for giving me a heads up on IIF statement.

Answer (score 1):

You could either read the values from a table or fill an array.  Both would work, but I prefer table-driven code because, for something like this, adding new search terms would only require you to add them to your table.

So, what I would do is first create a new table called tblSearchTerms.  In that table, create one field called SearchTerms, and put each of your terms (i.e. "Car", "Bike", etc...) in there, one per record.

Then set up a function in Access.  Open a Module (either a new one or one you already have, as long as it's a **Module**), and enter this:

```
Function SearchExists(sString As String) As String

Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select SearchTerms from tblSearchTerms")

Do while rec.EOF = False

  If InStr(1, sString, rec(0)) > 0 Then
    SearchExists = "" & rec(0) & ""
    Goto BugOut
  Else
  End If
Loop

SearchExists = "Not Found"

BugOut:
End Function
```

Now, what you do is create a query.  In that query, you'll have one field to check to see if your search term exists.  It will look something like this:

```
MySearchTerm: SearchExists([Cell1])
```

When you run your query, that field will either populate with one of the search terms (if it's found), or will return "Not Found".

This may require a bit of tweaking, because it's more for finding a search term in an Access table, so there's going to need to be some adjusting to make it work with Excel, but it's pretty close to what you need.

Comment: I will look into this, this could work, VBA i know. I though Microsoft had added a function to locate things like this but it might me trickier then i know. Thank for this and i'll be back

Comment: Thank you for this well structured code. I tried this and SunKnight0's suggestion. I went with the IIF statement since it's quick and dirty but i will start working with your way of thinking and introduce more VBA into Access.